# Find a repetitive sequence in a string

Tags: vb.net, string, algorithm

I would like to find repetitive sequence in a string in VB.Net, something like:

Dim test as String = "EDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGB"

I want the program to detect the repetitive sequence, in case EDCRFVTGB and to count how many times it is repeated. My problem is to find the repetitive sequence in the string, I searched several ways to do it but I did not get a solution, I tried quicksort algorithms, duplicate algorithms, but several of them don't work with strings.

I though about create substrings and check their existence in the string, but I don't know how to get the substring, since there is not a pattern on the string, also there is a possibility of no repetitive sequence in the string.

Comment: your problem is to find the longest repeating substring?

Comment: the code you would need to do something like this qould be comparable to the "Brute force" programs which guess passwords, and it would be very very slow to run through all possibilities of substrings and check vs all other substrings.

Comment: Is the format exactly as this or do you have unused pieces of text before / after / between the repeating string?

Comment: @1010 Well, I did not thought about the longest one, but finding only the longest one would fix my problem I guess.

Comment: @maraca The string has no fixed lenght, that was just an example, I may get something like "RANDOM TEST TEST OTHER TEST", then I want to get the word TEST and get the index of the start of each TEST word.

Comment: Hmm well I don't know how to explain what I'm thinking but you would have to define what a 'word' is in your code for it to return the value you expect, otherwise it will probably return a lot more than what u wanted.

For example, the string, "test one test". This has a 't' that occurs 4 times however it also has the word 'test' that occurs twice and an 'e' that occurs twice and you get the point. 

I'm not sure If you'll understand this because I'm pretty bad at explaining things but yea.

Comment: Do you know the pattern beforehand? What is the expected complexity for the algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

First check if half of the target string is repeated twice.  If not, check if a third of the string is repeated three times.  If not, check if one fourth of the string is repeated four times.  Do this until you find a matching sequence.  Skip any divisor where the quotient is not a whole number to make it perform better.  This code should do the trick and fill in any gaps that this description fails to clarify:

```
Public Function DetermineSequence(ByVal strTarget As String) As String

    Dim strSequence As String = String.Empty

    Dim intLengthOfTarget As Integer = strTarget.Length

    'Check for a valid Target string.
    If intLengthOfTarget > 2 Then

        'Try 1/2 of Target, 1/3 of Target, 1/4 of Target, etc until sequence is found.
        Dim intCursor As Integer = 2

        Do Until strSequence.Length > 0 OrElse intCursor = intLengthOfTarget

            'Don't even test the string if its length is not a divisor (to an Integer) of the length of the target String.
            If IsDividendDivisibleByDivisor(strTarget.Length, intCursor) Then

                'Get the possible sequence.
                Dim strPossibleSequence As String = strTarget.Substring(0, (intLengthOfTarget / intCursor))

                'See if this possible sequence actually is the repeated String.
                If IsPossibleSequenceRepeatedThroughoutTarget(strPossibleSequence, strTarget) Then

                    'The repeated sequence has been found.
                    strSequence = strPossibleSequence

                End If

            End If

            intCursor += 1

        Loop

    End If

    Return strSequence

End Function

Private Function IsDividendDivisibleByDivisor(ByVal intDividend As Integer, ByVal intDivisor As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim bolDividendIsDivisbleByDivisor As Boolean = False

    Dim intOutput As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse((intDividend / intDivisor), intOutput) Then

        bolDividendIsDivisbleByDivisor = True

    End If

    Return bolDividendIsDivisbleByDivisor

End Function

Private Function IsPossibleSequenceRepeatedThroughoutTarget(ByVal strPossibleSequence As String, ByVal strTarget As String) As Boolean

    Dim bolPossibleSequenceIsRepeatedThroughoutTarget As Boolean = False

    Dim intLengthOfTarget As Integer = strTarget.Length
    Dim intLengthOfPossibleSequence As Integer = strPossibleSequence.Length

    Dim bolIndicatorThatPossibleSequenceIsCertainlyNotRepeated As Boolean = False

    Dim intCursor As Integer = 1

    Do Until (intCursor * intLengthOfPossibleSequence) = strTarget.Length OrElse bolIndicatorThatPossibleSequenceIsCertainlyNotRepeated

        If strTarget.Substring((intCursor * intLengthOfPossibleSequence), intLengthOfPossibleSequence) <> strPossibleSequence Then

            bolIndicatorThatPossibleSequenceIsCertainlyNotRepeated = True

        End If

        intCursor += 1

    Loop

    If Not bolIndicatorThatPossibleSequenceIsCertainlyNotRepeated Then

        bolPossibleSequenceIsRepeatedThroughoutTarget = True

    End If

    Return bolPossibleSequenceIsRepeatedThroughoutTarget

End Function
```

Comment: This is not what he wants, see the comment in the question of him, I upvoted the comment now for better visibility.

Comment: I like this because it will test IF a string is a sequence, but I would have to agree that the desired output of this isn't going to produce the requested result. But I want to add that I think this is very creative and I like what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will allow you to specify the minimum and maximum length of a sequence and return a list of a custom class called sequence, where there is more than one occurrence. The sequence class will contain the found pattern and a list of indexes where the pattern occurs.

[image]

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        ListView1.Columns.Clear()
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Sequence")
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Indexes of occurrence")
        Dim sequences As List(Of Sequence) = DetectSequences("EDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGB")
        For Each s As Sequence In sequences
            Dim item As New ListViewItem(s.Sequence)
            item.Tag = s
            item.SubItems.Add(s.IndexesToString)
            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
        ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)
    End Sub
    Function DetectSequences(s As String, Optional minLength As Integer = 5, Optional MaxLength As Integer = 8) As List(Of Sequence)
        Dim foundPatterns As New List(Of String)
        Dim foundSequences As New List(Of Sequence)
        Dim potentialPattern As String = String.Empty, potentialMatch As String = String.Empty
        For start As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
            For length As Integer = 1 To s.Length - start
                potentialPattern = s.Substring(start, length)
                If potentialPattern.Length < minLength Then Continue For
                If potentialPattern.Length > MaxLength Then Continue For
                If foundPatterns.IndexOf(potentialPattern) = -1 Then
                    foundPatterns.Add(potentialPattern)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        For Each pattern As String In foundPatterns
            Dim sequence As New Sequence With {.Sequence = pattern}
            For start As Integer = 0 To s.Length - pattern.Length
                Dim length As Integer = pattern.Length
                potentialMatch = s.Substring(start, length)
                If potentialMatch = pattern Then
                    sequence.Indexes.Add(start)
                End If
            Next
            If sequence.Indexes.Count > 1 Then foundSequences.Add(sequence)
        Next
        Return foundSequences
    End Function
    Public Class Sequence
        Public Sequence As String = ""
        Public Indexes As New List(Of Integer)
        Public Function IndexesToString() As String
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            For i As Integer = 0 To Indexes.Count - 1
                If i = Indexes.Count - 1 Then
                    sb.Append(Indexes(i).ToString)
                Else
                    sb.Append(Indexes(i).ToString & ", ")
                End If
            Next
            Return sb.ToString
        End Function
    End Class
    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        RichTextBox1.Text = "EDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGBEDCRFVTGB"
        Dim selectedSequence As Sequence = DirectCast(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Tag, Sequence)
        For Each i As Integer In selectedSequence.Indexes
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = i
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = selectedSequence.Sequence.Length
            RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where the string starts?
Do you know how long it is?

The straightforward algorithm is:

```
for each character index i
    for each character index after that j
        compare substring(i, j-i) to substring(j, j-i)
        if equal, record as a found repeating substring
```

There are optimizations, such as knowing that strings can't go beyond the end of the string (upper limits on j) and only looking for substrings longer than what you've only found.

This is not super efficient (N-squared,) but a related generalized problem ("edit distance") is also known to not be better than N-squared, so there you go.

Comment: you also stop searching substrings after you've reached half the length of the string ;)

Comment: I don't know how long the string is, the string may be random characters, with no specific length, which may include spaces or not, and in these random characters I need to find if there is any sequence of characters repeated, the string will not be larger than 400-500 characters.

Based on what Andrew said, the code only detects repetitive sequence until the half of the string, however I would need to find that repetitive sequence, which can be the longest one only, even if it is at the end of the string.

Comment: Andrew suggested an optimization; he didn't suggest that the pseudo-code describes an incorrect algorithm. The algorithm is correct, and will find substrings of length 1 or longer no matter where in the string you find them. The main optimizations is what brings you from runtime O(N^3)-ish to guaranteed O(N^2), but as written, it works.

Answer (score -1):

This is an algorithm which generates all repeating sequences incremental in such a way that they are ordered by length and first occurence. It is based on a simple idea: to find a word twice in a sentence the same starting letter has to appear twice.

Java code with some explanation (algorithm stays the same), it will output interwoven repetitions, e.g. BANANA => A, N, AN, NA, ANA (1,3), you can eliminate an index if the distance to the one before is smaller than the string length to correct it in this algorithm (below the code is a sample run, which should explain it better):

```
public List<String> getRepetitions(String string) {
   List<String> repetitions = new ArrayList<String>();
   Map<String, List<Integer>> rep = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>(), repOld;
   // init rep, add start position of all single character length strings
   for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
      String s = string.substring(i, i + 1); // startIndex inclusive, endIndex exclusive
      if (rep.containsKey(s)) {
         rep.get(s).add(new Integer(i));
      } else {
         List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         l.add(new Integer(i));
         rep.put(l);
      }
   }
   // eliminate those with no repetitions and add the others to the solution
   for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : rep.entrySet()) {
      if (e.getValue().size() < 2) {
         rep.remove(e.getKey());
      } else {
         repetitions.add(e.getKey());
      }
   }
   for (int len = 1; rep.size() > 0; len++) {
      repOld = rep;
      rep = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
      for (Map.EntrySet<String, List<Integer>> e : repOld.entrySet()) {
         for (Integer i : e.getValue()) { // for all start indices
            if (i.intValue() + len + 1 >= string.length())
               break;
            String s = e.getKey() + string.charAt(i.intValue() + len + 1);
            if (rep.containsKey(s)) {
               rep.get(s).add(i);
            } else {
               List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
               l.add(i);
               rep.put(l);
            }
         } 
      }
      // eliminate repetitions and add to solution
      for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : rep.entrySet()) {
         if (e.getValue().size() < 2) {
            rep.remove(e.getKey());
         } else {
            repetitions.add(e.getKey());
         }
      }
   }
   return repetitions; // ordered by length, so last = longest
}
```

Sample run for BANANA:

1. add single letters to `rep` => B -> [0], A -> [1, 3, 5], N -> [2, 4]
2. eliminate those with less than 2 occurences (B), add others to solution (A, N)
3. add the following letter to the remaining occurances (create a new `rep`): AN -> [1, 3], NA -> [2, 4]
4. Eliminate (-) and add (AN, NA)
5. repetition of step 3. and 4.: ANA -> [1, 3]
6. in the cycle `rep` will become empty and the algorithm is finished

Comment: Down-voted because this question is asking for a VB.Net solution

Comment: @PaulIshak Here the algorithm matters... not the language and I'm pretty sure this is the most performant approach. I downvoted you because you don't explain anything... take this it does what you want... great, he will learn a lot from you.

Comment: Should he need more information, from experience, I know he will ask. My naming conventions explain it all, and if they don't, I will clarify at his request.

Comment: @PaulIshak well I can do the same, had written VB.NET, just not fluent any more at all... let me ask you a hypothetical question: Someone is looking for an algorithm in a language and nobody who knows the language knows the algorithm, but somebody who doesn't know the language knows the algorithm... would you prefer if he doesn't say anything and you never learn about it?

Comment: That's great for you! It is also GREAT that you laid down the steps of the algorithm for him as well. It really is! Honestly, I probably should have done the same. But the simple meat of it is that he asked for a solution in vb.net, and I down voted your C# answer! Why not convert your solution to vb.net and end this debate and I can un-down vote your post?

Comment: @PaulIshak you expect me to do his work? I give him the algorithm, he can write the program, I'm not googling the syntax for everything because I don't know it by heart. It's even in the FAQ that you shouldn't just post finished answers, especially if he doesn't provide a code snippet of what he already has, in this case I wouldn't post any Java code of course because it is just useless then. Algorithm matters here, not going to invest hours. Have a nice day. PS. Maybe this question is also found by other programmers in search engines.

Comment: I think the programming language is relevant, especially to people who have questions about tasks in that language. Best of luck to you!